# Django Authentication on different databases

Tags: django, authentication, multiple-databases

I want to create an App for Customers where every customer has its own DB. So as Login information they need to enter three different fields: customernumber, username, password.

The username and password should do the normal authentication stuff and the customernumber is there to go to the right database user table for authentication i can go to other databases through the using() method but how do you authenticate a user through the right database?

Answer (score 3):

You should write custom authentication backend like below and it must be specified on settings.py using AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS key. [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources)

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
class CustomAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.using(request.GET['CUSTOMER_TABLE']).filter(username=username)
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```