# How to use auth_user from another database(not default database)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two databases (default database and sample database) . I want to use `auth_user` table from sample database not from default database (by default , it is taking from default database ).i want specify it in my model file so that i can access in my views . how is this possible?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test@123',
        'HOST': '10.40.40.170',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'sample': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test@123',
        'HOST': '10.40.40.170',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

I have added one extra column for `auth_user` table from sample database. I want to use that table. (I can't use `auth_user` from default database, because my requirement is like that)

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/).
suppose i have 2 models (test1, test2).test1 is from sample1 database and test2 is from sample2 database.is it possible to mention in model file that test1 should come from sample1 database??

```
in model.py 
class tes1():
    class meta:
         app_label='users'
         db_table='auth_user'
         db_label='sample1' #database name here
```

Comment: The way you asked the question is not correct. Please make it more clear. What do you mean by it is taking from x database (are you using any program to access it ). You want this change in your program or in database itself... etc. Please make it more clear

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create Router for that.

Please go through following links

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/
- [Django ManyToMany through with multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018277/django-manytomany-through-with-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Django Authentication on different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836068/django-authentication-on-different-databases)
 and [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example)

Comment: auth_user is default django table for every database .. so that's y its not working think so